# How to run a background Cloud Function and schedule a change in database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing an app using React Native and Firebase Realtime database. I want to do something like this.

From the app, I set a time duration and press a button. Then, it writes data to the Firebase. Assume that I set the time duration to `1000000000 ms` and press the button. Then, the database looks like this:

```
schedules
  |
  |--schedule1
       |
       |--status: "Running"
       |--durationInMS: 1000000000
```

I want to run a background function that changes the above status to "TimeOver" after `1000000000 ms`. This function should be run in the background even if the app is closed:

```
schedules
      |
      |--schedule1
           |
           |--status: "TimeOver"
           |--durationInMS: 1000000000
```

How to do this?

Comment: Should this thread run paralell?

Comment: Yes. The particular function should be triggered when the button is pressed to add the schedule.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in trigger to run after a certain delay that is written in the database.

But you can either build your own scheduler using [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/), or create a regularly running [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) that then checks for expired schedules in your database.

Also see:

- [Cloud Functions for Firebase trigger on time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time)
- [How to create cron jobs in firebase programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56074188/how-to-create-cron-jobs-in-firebase-programmatically/56080274#56080274)
- [Executing cloud functions after n seconds on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56114875/executing-cloud-functions-after-n-seconds-on-demand/56115661#56115661)
- [Firebase Functions, run after 15 minutes of user inactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49178003/firebase-functions-run-after-15-minutes-of-user-inactivity/49178276#49178276)
- [How can we get Firestore to trigger an event when a document's Date/Time field matches current time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54993454/how-can-we-get-firestore-to-trigger-an-event-when-a-documents-date-time-field-m/54993483#54993483)
- [Scheduled Cloud Functions Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56332063/scheduled-cloud-functions-firebase/56332105#56332105)
- the blog post [How to schedule a Cloud Function to run in the future with Cloud Tasks (to build a Firestore document TTL)](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a)
- the article [Dynamic Scheduled Background Jobs in Firebase](https://fireship.io/lessons/cloud-functions-scheduled-time-trigger/)