# Firebase functions to trigger if the firebase timestamp reaches the time mentioned in any of the data

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm completely new to Firebase.Can someone help me to solve this asap. I have a document with values as mentioned below. If the current firebase server timestamp reaches the time mentioned in any of the triggerTime values then trigger the function to update the status

Doc Id :

Document Fields:

Name : StackOverFlow,

Id: 100001,

Status: false,

Triggertime:1620162615 (Epoch Unix Time)

If firebase server epoch time matches with triggertime then the status should be true.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57920578/how-to-run-a-background-cloud-function-and-schedule-a-change-in-database, https://fireship.io/lessons/cloud-functions-scheduled-time-trigger/ and https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.